# Wordpress: Looping a customer variable within a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a wordpress site and I would like to know if it is possible to do a loop on a custom field within the single template itself?

Below is the code that I am using to render a youtube video within a post.  All I record on the post itself is the youtube unique identifier.

```
 <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_youtube', true) ) : ?>
      <div class="youtube_video">
           <?php echo'
                <iframe width="570" height="395" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/';?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_youtube', true)?><?php echo'" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>
           ';
           ?>
      </div>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

What I want is for this code to loop for each time the custom variable 'video_youtube' is used on that post.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understood and what i got is, you want some way or some variable which when called produced youtube iframe code.

But I don't understand is its you who will decide how many times you want to use custom variable on your template. Are you sure you want custom variable? Or you want SHORT CODE instead? that can be filled through post/page or template.

try this

```
$youtube_embed = '
            <iframe width="570" height="395" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_id', true).'" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>
       ';

$youtube = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_youtube', true)?$youtube_embed;
```

now wherever you want to post youtube video, you can just echo $youtube

alternatively, if you need to pass video ID for each time you need video, you can create a small FUNCTION Or even a CLASS inside the template file.

```
function embedYoutube($video_link,$is_embed){
return '<iframe width="570" height="395" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video_link.'" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>
       ';}


echo embedYoutube(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_id', true),get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_youtube', true));
```